# Transitionend in CSS seems to fail, why?

Tags: javascript, css

So I'm attempting to modify a purely HTML/CSS version of the game KuKu Kube, adding a timer, more levels, and a standardized side, but I'll probably be able to figure those out.

So, I have this snippet of code:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("cube");

element.addEventListener("transitionend", showMessage(), false);
element.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', showMessage(), false);
element.addEventListener('oTransitionEnd', showMessage(), false);
element.addEventListener('transitionend', showMessage(), false);
element.addEventListener('msTransitionEnd', showMessage(), false);
```

I've spent at least an hour pouring over the code that was there before, and being a novice, my analysis is that the cubes are checkboxes, and they transition.

By the way, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/88naxrjo/16/) here, but I feel the reason it's not working is in those 5 lines.

So, why doesn't the transitionend trigger showMessage()?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns array, not single element.

Comment: Mike C's answer appears correct. Still though, I would imagine the `addEventListener` part would have been caught in the log of the developer tools? `addEventListener is undefined` might have been cryptic, but you could have perhaps narrowed the issue that way. Having the right tools to debug your code instead of just look closely at it is very helpful!

Comment: Yea. Once again, my the answer to my question was just a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're immediately calling `showMessage`, not setting it up as an event listener.

For example, if you did this:

```
var value = showMessage();
console.log(value);
```

You'd probably see `undefined` in your console. Instead, you want to pass the function itself as the argument, not it's return value.

```
element.addEventListener('transitionend', showMessage, false);
//                           Notice the lack of () --^
```

Also, if you open up your console, you'll see that you're getting a

> Uncaught TypeError: element.addEventListener is not a function

error. That's because `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of nodes, not an individual one. Instead, you should loop through that collection and attach the event to each individual node.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('cube');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var element = elements[i];
  element.addEventListener('transitionend', showMessage, false);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Great! Follow-up question, which one of these event listeners should be used for multiple browsers - mainly Chrome and Safari?

Comment: @LBMF_1 You should still use all of the events if you want to ensure it works across all browsers. Just use your same code but pass the function instead of calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically calling all elements with cube - so it's an array - you have to iterate over it to add listeners to all of them.
[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/88naxrjo/18/)

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("cube");

for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
element[i].addEventListener("transitionend", showMessage, false);
element[i].addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', showMessage, false);
element[i].addEventListener('oTransitionEnd', showMessage, false);
element[i].addEventListener('transitionend', showMessage, false);
element[i].addEventListener('msTransitionEnd', showMessage, false);
}
```